# JavaScript Too much recursion error with facebook JavaScript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

i am sending FB.login request to facebook. but FB is not defined while javascript SDK is still loading core javascript resources.

so, i put a check to get FB variable

```
function check_FB_variable(){
            if(typeof FB=='undefined'){
                check_FB_variable();
            }else{}
           }
           check_FB_variable();
```

But this approach gives me Too much recursion error.

so , i put this code as

```
function check_FB_variable(){
            if(typeof FB=='undefined'){
                setTimeout(check_FB_variable,600);
            }else{}
           }
           check_FB_variable();
```

but in this approach the before timeout function make a call function moves down and gives error 
FB.login not defined.

please, help.

Answer (score 0):

I've used something similar to check if JQMobi exists, I don't know exactly why but I think the exception is thrown because you call the pointer to the function every time.

You should try checking in an interval like this (Untested):
    var facebookChecker = window.setInterval(fbCheck, 200);

```
var fbCheck = function () {
    if (typeof FB != 'undefined' && facebookChecker != null) {
        window.clearInterval(facebookChecker);
        facebookChecker = null;

        // Whatever you want to do if facebook is loaded
        // Example: InitFBLogin();
    }
}
```

Or you could use a while statement (the one I used):

```
/*
*   This JQ Fix tries to attach Jquery to a variable to ensure it exists.
*   - Marvin Brouwer.
*/

var FixJQ = function () {
    var JQFIX = null;
    while (!JQFIX || JQFIX == null) {
        try {
            JQFIX = jQuery;
        } catch (nothing) {  jQuery =  $; };
    };
    JQFIX = null;
    return true;
};

if (FixJQ()) {
    FixJQ = null;
};
```

The beauty of the last one is that you can put you next step below this, because it will wait until the while loop has finished.
I honestly do not know which one is better/faster but I’m sure the bottom one will work.

Comment: you have used similar approach like i used as setTimeout, set timeInterval will call function 200ms but before this code below this will be executed. i want code to stop there only. i should proceed  to next line when FB is set.

Comment: It is true that the functionality is the same, however calling recursions can be detected as a faulty script by some browsers if they take a long time.
I had this experience with IE a lot.
SetInterval used to work but as I pointed out I did not test that one.
As for the other one, I have used this in a project and it did work.
However I had a script combining all my javascripts in to one file before pulishing my project so maybe that's the problem?

Comment: yes, you are right calling recursions is not a good practice in this type of conditions. anyway i put all my code inside the "check_FB_variable" function, so it solves the problem for me. i think it will be good if pass a callback function. hope, someone come up with a better solution.